# How to replace a fix location in each line in a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, numeric-data

I have a file as below, how do I replace the $number (location 19-30) and (location 59-70) with its number in cents.

update: All fields are required to stay at the same fixed location.

input:

```
asfdassdfasfasfas    1,719.41 23:55:51 016250    9003286     1,719.41    24.64DR 381000
safsdfoskjshfkkdf      184.00 23:57:53 019516    9007963       184.00     2.94DR 384000
agereafdfbfbgsdgd    1,168.00 23:59:55 012229    9002950     1,168.00     3.54DR 0000
```

desired ouput:

```
asfdassdfasfasfas      171941 23:55:51 016250    9003286       171941    24.64DR 381000
safsdfoskjshfkkdf       18400 23:57:53 019516    9007963        18400     2.94DR 384000
agereafdfbfbgsdgd      116800 23:59:55 012229    9002950       116800     3.54DR 0000
```

[image]

Comment: Are the columns delimited by spaces or tabs?

Comment: by spaces, the html code messes up the text file, but it's fixed location

Answer (score 1):

Good old `awk`

Using fixed field widths for input, trimming fields `$2` and `$4` as required and then padding them back to the original widths

```
awk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "19 11 29 11 30"} {
     gsub(/\.|,/,"",$4); gsub(/\.|,/,"",$2);
     printf "%s%11s%s%11s%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
}' file1
```

This should be a general solution as the character removal is insensitive to context and it does not matter how many characters are removed, the field will always be padded back to the correct width (11)

Gzin

```
cat file1
asfdassdfasfasfas    1,719.41 23:55:51 016250    9003286     1,719.41    24.64DR 381000
safsdfoskjshfkkdf      184.00 23:57:53 019516    9007963       184.00     2.94DR 384000
agereafdfbfbgsdgd    1,168.00 23:59:55 012229    9002950     1,168.00     3.54DR 0000
```

Gzout

```
asfdassdfasfasfas      171941 23:55:51 016250    9003286       171941    24.64DR 381000
safsdfoskjshfkkdf       18400 23:57:53 019516    9007963        18400     2.94DR 384000
agereafdfbfbgsdgd      116800 23:59:55 012229    9002950       116800     3.54DR 0000
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated :** For the updated question ,Try below which only works for the exact input scenario

```
sed -Ee 's/([0-9]),([0-9]{3})./  \1\2/g;s/ ([0-9]{3})\./  \1/g' <<inputFile>>
```

Output : .

```
$ sed -Ee 's/([0-9]),([0-9]{3})./  \1\2/g;s/ ([0-9]{3})\./  \1/g'  temp.txt 
asfdassdfasfasfas      171941 23:55:51 016250    9003286       171941    24.64DR 381000
safsdfoskjshfkkdf       18400 23:57:53 019516    9007963        18400     2.94DR 384000
agereafdfbfbgsdgd      116800 23:59:55 012229    9002950       116800     3.54DR 0000 

    $ head -1 temp.txt 
    asfdassdfasfasfas    1,719.41 23:55:51 016250    9003286     1,719.41    24.64DR 381000
    $ head -1 temp.txt  | wc -c
    88
    $ sed -Ee 's/([0-9]),([0-9]{3})./  \1\2/g;s/ ([0-9]{3})\./  \1/g' | head -1
    asfdassdfasfasfas      171941 23:55:51 016250    9003286       171941    24.64DR 381000
    $ sed -Ee 's/([0-9]),([0-9]{3})./  \1\2/g;s/ ([0-9]{3})\./  \1/g' temp.txt | head -1 | wc -c
    88
```

**( General )** You can do with awk by treating each column value as field , not as whole string :

```
awk  '{gsub(",",""); $2=$2*100;$6=$6*100; }1' <<inputFile>>  | rev | column -t | rev
```

Output :

```
asfdassdfasfasfas   171941  23:55:51    016250  9003286 171941  24.64DR 381000  
safsdfoskjshfkkdf   18400   23:57:53    019516  9007963 18400   2.94DR  384000  
agereafdfbfbgsdgd   116800  23:59:55    012229  9002950 116800  3.54DR  0000
```

Comment: Thanks, but this removes the "," and "." so it shrink the record meaning the original fixed fields are shifted.

Comment: @user408286 : This will not remove "." , it will just remove "," and multiply it with 100 as u want..

Comment: yes, but it also shifts other fields. All other field/data has to remain in the same fixed location, except the $ amounts

Comment: @user408286 : the updated one with 'sed' works for your input..